# Obsolete command \Bbb

Tags: math-mode, warnings

A warning keeps popping up in my LaTeX editor, and it's really annoying. It says that the command `\Bbb` is obsolete and I should use `\mathbb` instead. I personally like the command `\Bbb` by the obvious reason that its shorter than the newer one. If the command `\Bbb` is obsolete then why don't they take it out? If I try to make a new command to redefine `\Bbb` as `\mathbb`, the compiler won't let me. Is there a way to get rid of this warning?

Comment: `\let\Bbb\mathbb` works for me.

Comment: Also `\renewcommand{\Bbb}{\mathbb}` should. :)

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much. I didn't know those commands. All I tried was `\newcommand`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since some years the command `\Bbb` provided by `amsfonts` has been renamed to `\mathbb` to conform to the other font selection commands (`\mathcal`, `\mathbf` and so on).

The command `\Bbb` has so been redefined to give a warning at the first usage, but then it works exactly as `\mathbb`.

Of course you're free to redefine it as you please:

```
\usepackage{amssymb} % or amsfonts
\renewcommand{\Bbb}{\mathbb}
```

In this way you'll not get any warning.

Why hasn't it been removed? Because many legacy documents use it.

Comment: As for the way: In other words, backwards compatibility... This enables users to recompile documents written decades ago.

Answer (score 8):

I suspect you are using this command all over the place to typeset something like a matrix or perhaps a set of numbers.
You should try to separate style from content, while at the same time save your fingers from excessive typing.

```
\newcommand{\set}[1]{\mathbb{#1}}
...
$ x \in \set{N} $
```

Both short and readable, and, if ever necessary, simple to change styling (e.g. you wish to use some other font for sets).