# \BbbN vs \mathbb{N}

Tags: xetex, luatex, unicode-math

Following [Obsolete comand \Bbb](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51530/obsolete-comand-bbb) and http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/22142/difference-between-mathbb-and-bbb, though `\Bbb` seems deprecated, `\BbbN` is not. It is in unimath-symbols.pdf. Same for `\BbbA`, `\BbbB`, etc. What's the difference between `\BbbN` and `\mathbb{N}` in unicode-math for xe/lua-latex?

Comment: `\BbbN` is an internal command; when you do `\mathbb{N}` or `\symbb{N}`, this is mapped to `\BbbN` automatically. Note that the deprecated form is `\Bbb{N}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command `\Bbb` was introduced, as far as I remember, by `amstex` (an obsolete command), but later renamed `\mathbb`.

The command is still defined by `amssymb`, but only for back compatibility with older documents and it triggers a warning. It should not be used in newer ones.

Unfortunately, MathJax allows it, which however is not a good reason for using it.

Commands such as `\BbbN` are a different thing: they are internal commands defined by `unicode-math`, which maps calls like `\mathbb{N}` (or `\symbb{N}`) to `\BbbN`. It is possible to use them directly, but I'd not recommend doing it, as you lose in flexibility.

Much better is doing as I recommend in the answer to the referenced Meta question on Math.SE:

```
\newcommand{\numberset}[1]{{\mathbb{#1}}}

\newcommand{\RR}{\numberset{R}}
\newcommand{\NN}{\numberset{N}}
```

This way you can change the appearance of *every* such symbol by just changing the definition of `\numberset`.