# What does \bbbn mean?

Tags: macros

In a LaTeX document, I found the definition of a structure as `{\cal_A}_0 = (bbbn; 0; s; =)` (written as literals appearing in the compiled document, not as source code and / or in math mode).
What could the '\bbbn' mean? From the context, something like $\mathhbb{N}$ would be possible, but I am not sure and it could be everything else from the subject computability theory. I cannot ask the author.

Comment: The relation does not seem to make sense, there is no `\` in front of `bbbn`, so it could well mean `b times b times b times n` and use `\mathcal{A}` instead of `{\cal A}`.

Comment: There is an obsolete `amsmath` macro `\Bbb` which was replaced by `\mathbb`, so `\Bbbn` would yield `\mathbb{n}`. It's still in `amssymb`. But the semicolons here make me wonder if this is some CSS from somewhere. Is this Mathjax source?

Comment: See e.g. [\BbbN vs \mathbb{N}](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/339523)

Comment: If you post the two comments as one answer, I will grant you the best solution. Thanks! The semikolon is context specific, it is printed as-is and serves as a separator for the different entries of a [structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_(mathematical_logic))

Comment: @AlanMunn please see above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an obsolete `amsmath` command `\Bbb`, which was replaced by `\mathbb` and `\Bbbn` would therefore be equivalent to `\Bbb{n}`, i.e., `\mathbb{n}`. The symbol still exists in `amssymb` for backwards compatibility purposes.  It also still exists in MathJax source.

See: [\BbbN vs \mathbb{N}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339523/2693)